# How do I use the numeric notification "bubble" in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to use the iOS notification image (the numeric bubble shown over app icons). How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done either through a [local or push notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) or setting the [application badge number property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;
```